# VirtualBox open few windows for 1 virtual machine

Tags: window, virtual-machine, virtualbox

When I start a virtual machine, the 3 windows of this virtual machine appear. It begins after changes normal, scale and full window mode.

As I found out - this windows represent one virtual machine - I can move terminal from window1 to window 2.
I have 2 monitors and maybe this is reason. But I don't know how to start with only 1 window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in the machine settings

Display -> Display count to 1

save.